# How do you call a method both "inside" and "outside" an instance in python?

Tags: python, oop

I don't really know how to describe this but one example will be like:
In Sympy, if you want to get a conjugate of an expression, you can do either

```
from sympy.abc import x
x.conjugate()
```

or

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import conjugate
conjugate(x)
```

I think what happens here is that x.conjugate will return a function with x as the argument.
Is there a simple or "standard" way to implement features like this?

Comment: In `x.conjugate()`, `x` is implicitly passed as the first argument to the method `conjugate` -- an argument traditionally named `self`. In `conjugate(x)`, you're just filling in `self` explicitly.

Comment: So `conjugate` could well just be a module-level reference to a method. No magic to make those, just `funcname = MyClass.funcname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply implement one in terms of the other:

```
# Approach 1
def conjugate(thing):
    # logic goes here

class Thing:
    # This looks strange, but inside the method, the global version is looked up.
    def conjugate(self):
        return conjugate(self)

x = Thing() # create the instance used elsewhere
```

---

```
# Approach 2
class Thing:
    def conjugate(self):
        # logic goes here

x = Thing() # create the instance used elsewhere

def conjugate(thing):
    return thing.conjugate() # use the method.

# Or you can alias the method this way:
# conjugate = Thing.conjugate
```

Comment: Explaining why all of this works the way it does is a much broader topic, probably better addressed by a tutorial or reference material than on StackOverflow. It also depends on how much technical detail you want.